# HPET missing from available clocksources on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I am having trouble using HPET on my physical machine.  It is not available, even though I have enabled it in my bios, forced it in grub, and triple checked my kernel to include HPET in its compilation.

- Motherboard: Supermicro X9DRW
- Processor: 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640
- SAS Controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2004 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Spitfire] (rev 03)
- Distro: CentOS 6.3
- Kernel: 3.4.21-rt32 #2 SMP PREEMPT RT x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Grub: hpet=force clocksource=hpet

.config file:

```
CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y 
CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y 
CONFIG_HPET=y
```

dmesg | grep hpet:

```
Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xxxx-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_xxxx/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_xxxx/lv_swap rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rhgb quiet panic=5 hpet=force clocksource=hpet
Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xxxx-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_xxxx/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_xxxx/lv_swap rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rhgb quiet panic=5 hpet=force clocksource=hpet
```

cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource:

```
tsc
```

cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource:

```
tsc jiffies
```

What is even more confusing, is that I have about a dozen other machines that utilize the same kernel .config, and can use HPET fine.  I fear it is a hardware issue, but would appreciate any advice or help with getting HPET available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hardware issue (grrr... Supermicro)... check your BIOS settings... Are they consistent across the servers? Are those servers the same model/build? Is this a trading system? How did you build the realtime kernel?

Comment: I checked my BIOS and have HPET enabled; and it is consistent across the servers.  This is the only machine that is having trouble.  The servers differ slightly in hardware -- what do you mean by trading system?  In regards to the kernel, I patched using the latest RT 3.4.x patch (matched with the same kernel version).  I copied my .config from another working machine, verified with menuconfig, then make all, make modules_install, make install (all with -j flags).

Comment: I asked about trading (e.g. Financial Trading) because that's the most common application for a realtime kernel setup and the timer modifications you're making.

Comment: Ah, it is a game server.

Comment: So what is in `dmesg`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have included it below: http://serverfault.com/questions/459901/hpet-missing-from-available-clocksources-on-centos/460170#comment506109_460170

Answer (score 1):

Additional info would be useful

- `dmesg|grep -i hpet` - for some `HPET` related information.
- `dmidecode` - BIOS version part.

Also [upgrading BIOS](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/) should probably help.

PS. Why not `TSC`? It's faster and if you have both `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc` in `/proc/cpuinfo` it's definitely the best choice.

Comment: `# dmesg|grep -i hpet`

`Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_volm-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_volm/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_volm/lv_swap rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rhgb quiet panic=5 hpet=force clocksource=hpet`


`Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_volm-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_volm/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_volm/lv_swap rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rhgb quiet panic=5 hpet=force clocksource=hpet`

Comment: `dmidecode`

`BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
        Version: 1.0a
        Release Date: 04/26/2012
`

Comment: Try upgrading BIOS to `1.0b`

Comment: I ended up resolving this by reflashing the BIOS and reinstalling CentOS 6.3.  Thanks for everyone's help -- this was definitely a thorn.